# Opening a Toplevel windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to open a toplevel window with a label from a function call but the label is not showing. What am I doing wrong?
Gratias.

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter.font as fonte


def open_top():   
    top = Toplevel(master)
    top.geometry("375x238+789+479")
    top.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    topFont = fonte.Font(family='Ubuntu', size=40)
    label = Label(top, text='world', borderwidth=2, relief="sunk", width=24)
    label.config(font = topFont, height=11, wraplength=350)
    label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)
    master.update()

# creating main tkinter window
master = Tk()
master.geometry("374x340+790+100")
master.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
myFont = fonte.Font(family='Monospace', size=25)
view = Label(master, text='helo', borderwidth=2, relief="sunk", width=10)
view.config(font = ('Monospace', 36), height=3)
view.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)

btn = Button(master, text ='toplevel', command = lambda: open_top())
btn.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=1, pady=4, padx=4)
btn = Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.destroy)
btn.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=1, pady=4, padx=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: you have two variables with the same name, what do you think that does (does it do anything tho)? also it can simply be `command=open_top`

Comment: Why do you have `height=11`? That isn't in pixels but in characters. Therefore, the label is somewhere bellow to the right corner of the toplevel. Remove the `top.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)` and try making the toplevel fullscreen.

Comment: @Matiiss I think I am blind. Which 2 variables.

Comment: @TheLizzard `btn`, the last 6 to 2 lines have the same variable name, but now thinking about it, it shouldn't affect the function call

Comment: @Matiiss I am blind. And yes, it isn't going to effect the function call. But it's still bad practice.

Comment: if you add `anchor='nw'` when creating the label, you will be able to see the text, the reason being what @TheLizzard already explained (2nd comment from top in case you don't see it), alternatively you can simply remove the `width` and `height` arguments (from the Label)

Comment: @Matiiss Do you want to write an answer? I can't right now.

Comment: Sorry about the double var, the sample code vas condensed from a larger script and YES, height 11 was the culprit. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

First about the problem:
When you create the label, you specify the width (and later) height arguments. Since your label contains text the units you pass as values to those arguments represent characters for width and lines for height ([You can read about those attributes here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/label.html))

@TheLizzard mention: `wraplength`'s value also is in characters, and since you have set it to 350 and your font is not that small, it will wrap the text when a huge part of it is out of the window (and quite possibly even out of the screen) so with the current value it is quite useless. (it is also quite useless if you add static text because then you can simply add a newline or sth, a use case would be when you don't know how long the text is, for example, it was taken from user input)

Possible fixes:

- Remove the width and height arguments (really the easiest):

```py
label = Label(top, text='world', borderwidth=2, relief="sunk")
label.config(font=topFont, wraplength=350)
```

The widget can be also configured all at once, you don't need to use its method like this for initialization:

```py
label = Label(top, text='world', borderwidth=2, relief="sunk", font=topFont, wraplength=350)
```

- Change the height and width values (width tho really doesn't have to be used, especially if you use the `wraplength` argument):

```py
label = Label(top, text='world', borderwidth=2, relief="sunk", font=topFont, wraplength=350, height=1)
```

- Use anchor (really not that much of a fix or anything but will allow you to see the text (to an extent)):

```py
label.config(anchor='nw')
```

---

Few other things:

**Important** (suggestions)
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Also: I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but use if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

Comment: Nice answer but you might also want to mention that the `wraplength=350` is useless in this case.

Comment: @TheLizzard added (at the top, after the link, in case you don't see it)